# Is there more efficient way than this if statement for large data in python

Tags: python, performance, if-statement, bigdata, processing-efficiency

So I am dealing with a large data file which has 1.3 million rows.
What I'm trying to do is simple, I want to change values in some columns given some conditions.

```
for i in range(0,len(data2)):    #where len(data2) is about 1.3 million
    if data2.loc[i,'PPA']==0:
        data1.loc[i,'LDU']=0        #(data1 and data2 have same amount of rows)
```

and I will also need to format for some other columns. for example, I want to format gender as either 0 or 1.

data as follows:

```
    data['Gender']

    Out[156]: 
    0          F
    1          M
    2          F
    3          F
          ..
    1290573    M
    1290574    F
    Name: Gender, Length: 1290575, dtype: object


#Format to 0 and 1
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    if data.loc[i,'Gender']=='F':
        data.loc[i,'Gender']=0;
    else:
        data.loc[i,'Gender']=1
```

Btw regarding the processing time, I noticed something unusual...
I saved the first 5000 rows to a new csv file, when I test my code on the sample data, it performed well and fast, like in 10 seconds.
But when I try to run it on my real data, and let it do

```
for i in range(0,10000) #instead of the full length of data
```

it takes about 9 minutes.

last time I formatted another column like this(assigning 0 and 1) on my full data takes more than 10 hours in python. So I'm just wondering if there anything wrong on my codes? is any other more efficient way to let it read and rewrite faster?  ...

Any help would be appreciated! :)

I'm kinda new to python and it's my first question post, thank you everyone for your comment :)

Comment: Please show an example input and an example output. For sure there is a more efficient way, you should not be iterating through the DF.

Comment: Could you use pandas and then use vectored operations? 10 hours sounds extreme, even for that much data

Comment: What is the type of `data1.loc`? I suspect you'll want to be using something like `numpy.array`, probably structured arrays: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html
You'll probably wind up with something like `data1[data2.loc[i,'PPA']==0, 'LDU'] = 0`.

Comment: @vash_the_stampede no, I think 10 hour run time for this kind of problem is effectively "not working"

Comment: @roganjosh I defer to you then

Comment: `data1['LDU'][data2['PPA'] == 0] = 0`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thank you soooo much!!! It works in seconds!! And thank you SuperStew, Ben and everyone else!! Have a good weekend! : )

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Wouldn't that be an example of chained assignment which is [supposed to be avoided in Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data)? I'm not sure about this, but it seems like using `loc`, as with Ben's answer, is the safer approach.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loops you can try [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Gender':['M','F']})
df['Numeric_Gender'] = np.where(df.Gender=='M',1,0)
df
Gender  Numeric_Gender
M        1
F        0
```